# How can i customize visual studio online bug template?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to customize bug template by add some field and change selection values, but I does find any documents about this, so is it supported? or how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not currently supported... But...

Visual Studio Online Process Customization is on the Microsoft's roadmap. Check the article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/05/visual-studio-online-process-customization.aspx